# Potential leak of an object, even in ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

Am using the following code and is using ARC

```
NSString *text;
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
FeedsCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[FeedsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (indexPath.row == [feedsData count]-1)
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];

    OnDemand_fetch *getData = [[OnDemand_fetch alloc] init];

    if(nextUrl != NULL)
    {

        NSString *nextfbUrl = [getData getnextFbfeedUrl];
        NSString *nexturlEdited = [nextfbUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@"%7C"];
        [demandfetch getFeedsInBackground:nexturlEdited];



    }
    else
    {
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        self.myTableView.tableFooterView=nil;
     }
```

while analyzing, shows warning :
"Potential leak of an object allocated on line 267 and stored into 'getData'."

Can anyone suggest the method to avoid this? will this cause any trouble?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's ARC? That looks fine to me. Is `getData` used anywhere else?

Comment: ya..am sure, i dont use the getData object anywhere else.

Comment: Change `OnDemand_fetch *getData = [[OnDemand_fetch alloc] init];` to `OnDemand_fetch *getData = [[[OnDemand_fetch alloc] init] autorelease];`. Does that bring about any errors when building?

Comment: no error! but am using ARC! why this kind of strange bheviour?

Comment: if the compiler allowed you to use `autorelease`, then you are not using ARC. ARC forbids calling autorelease.

Comment: Have you added the option "-fno-objc-arc" in Build Phases/Compile Sources for this particular file? As the other say if the compiler allows you to use ``autorelease`` then you are not using ARC, at least not for this particular file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> no error! but am using ARC! why this kind of strange bheviour?

Because...you're not using ARC. Not sure why you thought you were. To convert to ARC, go to Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC.

[image: How to convert to Objective-C ARC]

If you don't want to go all out, and ARC everything, you can add `-fobjc-arc` as a compiler flag to files that you want to use ARC, with the Project being non-ARC.

Comment: NB: you need to convert each target in a project to ARC individually! Ran into this myself, thought I had converted to ARC, but no. To check: Project -> target -> Build Settings, see if CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC is set to Yes. (Use the filter box to search for "arc")

Answer (score 0):

You are only using the `getData` object inside the `if(nextUrl != NULL)` block, you can try to move it to the block and make it `nil` at the end, something like this:

```
if(nextUrl != NULL)
{
    OnDemand_fetch *getData = [[OnDemand_fetch alloc] init];
    NSString *nextfbUrl = [getData getnextFbfeedUrl];
    NSString *nexturlEdited = [nextfbUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@"%7C"];
    [demandfetch getFeedsInBackground:nexturlEdited];
    getData = nil;
}
```

Comment: there is no need for this if he is truly using ARC. ARC recognizes when an object goes out of scope and releases it.

Comment: totally agree, I think the problem reside in that he's not using ARC in this particular file